# Identify T-shaped constellation

Tags: amateur-observing, identify-this-object, constellations

What is this T-shaped constellation? Never seen it before and it’s not on the map. The photo is made from south-west London facing west at 23-15 on 25.02.2023.[image]

Comment: That's Orion...

Comment: @GregMiller You should make that an answer (better said, **the** answer). Answers can be short.

Comment: what I'd like to know is what exactly that antenna has been pointed at

Comment: This is a very nice photo and the answers are correct and good. I would be interested in what exactly you describe as "T-shape". Just to satisfy this curiosity: Could edit and ammend a smaller version of the photo where you paint on top of it the T which you saw? It's such a wonderful example of how different people see different shapes when not influenced by what one *should* see :)

Comment: @uhoh the antenna's most likely pointing at [Crystal Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Palace_transmitting_station)

Comment: Interesting that I'm so used to seeing Orion, that I can't see the 'T'.

Comment: To see ‘T’, draw a perpendicular line from the bright star just above the chimney to Orion’s belt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

From in-the-sky.org's Planetarium function for London on said date and time, we can see that Orion's belt is about 17° above the horizon in the west-south-west.

---

@Greg Miller's comment is close:

> That's Orion..

But I'll propose a correction, that's a *very nice photo* of [Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_(constellation)) :-)

To prove that, see my snapshot of Orion et al. in [this answer to *What's the orange star I can see in the sky right now?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61089/12102)

The three stars in a row just beloiw the antenna are [Orion's Belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion%27s_Belt) and the "straight line" dropping down and slightly to the left from it is Orion's sword.

And the slightly fuzzy blob in the sword is the [Orion Nebula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_Nebula)

---

[image: This is a photo of the Orion Nebula taken on the 16th of Janurary 2016 https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Orion_Nebula,_16.01.2016.jpg]

**above:** [This is a photo of the Orion Nebula taken on the 16th of Janurary 2016](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Orion_Nebula,_16.01.2016.jpg) **below:** [Composite from two images taken with Canon 85mm / 1.8, taken while Orion was nearly overhead in Bali](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Orion_composite1.jpg)

[image: Composite from two images taken with Canon 85mm / 1.8, taken while Orion was nearly overhead in Bali. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Orion_composite1.jpg]

Comment: Envisioning the stars dangling down the middle as a sword is an ancient Greek interpretation. Other civilizations have envisioned those stars as depicting something else, typically a male body part.

Comment: @DavidHammen oh... kay... like [Uranus](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41977/why-was-neptune-rather-than-uranus-chosen-as-an-archetype#comment86327_41977) this is a reference we're not likely to be using as our "go-to term".

Comment: Many civilizations considered Orion's belt a huge waist of space.  That's why they only gave it three stars.

Comment: @GregMiller you made me laugh in public - luckily only a quiet coffee shop and not the library :-)

Comment: Apparently in Finnish folklore the belt and sword were seen as a scythe (Väinämöisen viikate; the Scythe of Väinämöinen), with the sword as the shaft and the belt as the blade like a reversed 7.