# Finding ones way around the sky

Tags: star, constellations

Thinking about this recent question [Identify T-shaped constellation](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/52015/identify-t-shaped-constellation) the first thing I have to say is that I applaud the poster for actually looking up and noticing the stars: something that becomes harder every year, particularly from a city like London.

I remember coming across mention of a classic book called something like "The Sky by Clock and Hand", which went a bit further than the usual "star finder" disc by guiding the reader between constellations by stepping around the sky using a handspan as the unit of angle.

Does anybody recognise the book? Is it still in print, and if not is there a PDF anywhere that could be recommended as a useful learning resource?

Googling for the two words "handspan" and "angle" turn up some useful resources, albeit not a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, an old question, but I believe this is the book you're looking for.

[image: The Stars by Clock and Fist]

I was always partial to HA Rey's [The Stars: A New Way to See Them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars:_A_New_Way_to_See_Them).

Comment: +1 for HA Rey. My copy is over 60 years old and very worn.

Comment: It's not old enough for you to not get credit for the answer. Thanks very much :-)